# FingerPrint userauthenticate delay issue - Samsung S8 Device

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Finger print authenticate issue occur only in Samsung S8 device running in Android Oreo 8.0.0 OS version.

App in S8 takes 3 to 4 seconds to authenticate the user if setUserAuthenticatedRequired(true).

> 03-08 16:20:47.955 E/Log-6   (30285): 3
>
> 03-08 16:20:47.980 V/SemIrisManager(30285): Service connected!
>
> 03-08 16:20:50.021 E/Log-6   (30285): 4

```
  mKeyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                        // of the key
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
```

When settingsetUserAuthenticatedRequired(false) app works fine,there is no delay and not printing SemIrisManager: service connected in Logs.

3 second delays visible in logs when showing fingerprint dialog. In samsung note8 issue not found.